# DataSet using first value as column header

Tags: c#, dataset, oledb

I have a piece of code where I want to extract values from the A column of an Excel sheet. Right now, here is the code I'm using and having an issue with:

```
m_connString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + m_source + "; Extended properties = 'Excel 12.0; HDR = NO; IMEX = 1;';";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(m_connString)) 
{

  conn.Open();
  DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaGuid(Tables, null);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  string defaultSheet = ExcelSheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
  OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + defaultSheet + "]", conn);
  OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);

  // Bug appears here
  adapter.fill(ds)


  // Fill a List<string> with the data found
  for (int r = 0; r < ds.Tables[0].Row.Count; r++)
  {
    m_list.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[r][0].ToString();
  }

}
```

What is happening is that, if I have an Excel file with the following content in the A column:

```
Row1
Row2
Row3
...
RowX
```

...What I end up getting is all values except for the first value (Row1). It turns out that Row1 is being used as a column name(?) for the DataSet's table. However, I don't want there to be any column names or headers, and I specifically state this in the connection string.

How can I prevent this behavior so I can have all my data placed in the List? Or, failing that, how can I work around this issue and extract Row1 from that DataSet?

Comment: I have few questions related to above code. 1) Why `DataTable dt` is created and what is usage of `GetOleDbSchemaGuid`? 2) What is `ExcelSheets`?

Comment: Syntax errors: 1) `adapter.fill(ds)` line is not ending with `;` and fill should be `Fill`. 2) `ds.Tables[0].Row` should be `ds.Tables[0].Rows` in for loop condition.

Answer (score 2):

Check [**Microsoft Reference**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) to understand how `Extended Properties` of the connection `HDR=NO` works:

> **Column headings**: By default, it is assumed that the first row of your
>   Excel data source contains columns headings that can be used as field
>   names. If this is not the case, you must turn this setting off, or
>   your first row of data "disappears" to be used as field names. This is
>   done by adding the optional HDR= setting to the Extended Properties of
>   the connection string. The default, which does not need to be
>   specified, is HDR=Yes. **If you do not have column headings, you need to
>   specify HDR=No; the provider names your fields F1, F2, etc.**

Here is example:

**Excel File Data (test.xlsx)**:

[image]

**Code**:

```
string m_source = "test.xlsx";    
string m_connString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; 
                        Data Source = " + m_source + @"; 
                        Extended properties = 'Excel 12.0; 
                        HDR= NO; 
                        IMEX = 1;';";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(m_connString)) 
{
     conn.Open();         
     string squery = "SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM [Sheet1$]"; 
     OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(squery, conn);
     OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);                
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(ds);        
}
```

**DataSet Visualizer**:

[image]

Comment: Well, I tried using F1 in my SQL command instead of *, though when i try to fill the dataset, I get the following OleDbException: "No value given for one or more required parameters". It still seems to be that the code is still treating the first row as a column header, as when i change the Excel file's A1 cell to "F1", this command works just fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show original code you are using? Code in question seems not valid. "adapter.fill" and "datatable.Row" should not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
    DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];

    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        string cName = table.Rows[0][column.ColumnName].ToString();
        if (!table.Columns.Contains(cName) && cName != "")
        {
            column.ColumnName = cName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the sql to something along the lines of this

```
"SELECT * FROM [" + defaultSheet + "] Except  Select Top(1)"
```